# Faces clipping between other faces

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces, topology, clipping

I selected partially the torso and arms and made a duplicate out of the selection, with the idea of creating a coat to cover the body. The thing is that i did a temporal join of the arms and torso, explaining the face clipping here:[image: Faces from the torso clipping through the faces from the arms]

What i want from this is a way to clip those leftovers inside the arm's circumference, and those little faces clipping over inside the torso, without deleting the entire face because it'll leave a gap and therefore the solution will be doing it manually.

[image]

I'm not familiarized with some of the tools that blender brings to the table, so I dont know if what I'm requesting is possible without doing it manually.

**EDIT:** So i tried the first suggestion of using the Boolean modifier, and after messing  around with the settings, i got what i wanted but there were tiny faces still clipping through, so it might not work for me because it requires exact precision from me.

Then tried the second suggestion of using Intersect (Boolean) from the face panel in Edit mode, and it works! Got confused by a second because i thought it'll automatically get rid of the leftovers, but just cuts them so you just select and remove, and thats what i needed.

[image]

[image]

Just adjust some parts of the geometry and im good to go!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly but maybe you can use bool modifier to cut those faces?

Comment: Oh, i just did a tiny investigation about the Boolean modifier that you mentioned and i think it will solve my problem! just positioning a cilinder inside the sleeve. Thanks, i had no idea!

Comment: but what will happen to the geometry that intersections the torso and the arms, will they merge or the vertices will be loose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you model your object won't give the best topology, but to answer your question, select the sleeve and try a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (or *Face* panel) > *Intersect (Boolean)*:

[image]

Result (choose *Union* or *Difference* depending on the part of the cylinder you want to keep):

[image]

Comment: I wanna replicate what you did in your answer, did you created the hollow cilinder inside Edit mode or is a mesh out of the mesh to edit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, both the 2 meshes are part of the same object, if this is your question, with this function you can boolean meshes within the same object

Comment: Oh, sorry! I dont know why it took me so long to figure that you recreated the sleeve - torso intersection. I'll give it a shot!